# Prove that the diameter is lower or equal to the half of the perimeter in a closed, convex and planar curve

Tags: proof-verification, plane-curves, plane-geometry, convex-geometry

I'm trying to prove the following statement

> Prove that the diameter is lower or equal to the half of the perimeter in a closed, convex and planar curve.

Is my proof correct?

> $\textbf{My attempt:}$
>
> Let $\gamma: I \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ a closed and convex planar curve and $D$ the diameter of $\gamma(I)$ considering the Euclidean distance $d$.
>
> Since $\gamma(I) \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ is compact, we know that there is a closed ball with radius $r$ containing $\gamma(I)$ and such that $r \leq \frac{D}{\sqrt{3}}$ by [Jung's theorem in the plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jung%27s_theorem)
>
> Clearly, $\frac{D}{4} \leq \frac{D}{\sqrt{3}}$, then we choose $r = \frac{D}{4}$ and we have that the diameter of $\gamma(I)$ is lower or equal to diameter of a closed ball, i.e.,
>
> $$D \leq 2r = 2 \frac{D}{4} = \frac{D}{2},$$
>
> but the diameter of $\gamma(I)$ is lower or equal to the perimeter $L$ of $\gamma(I)$, i.e., $D \leq L$, then
>
> $$D \leq 2r = 2 \frac{D}{4} = \frac{D}{2} \leq \frac{L}{2},$$
>
> which concludes that $D \leq \frac{L}{2} \ \square$.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't understand your attempt; in particular when you say "then we choose $r={D\over4}$". In my view we don't need Jung's theorem.

Since $\gamma(I)$ is compact there are two points $p$, $q\in\gamma(I)$ with $|p-q|=D$. These two points divide $\gamma$ into two parts $\gamma'$, $\gamma''$, each of them connecting $p$ with $q$, hence of length $\geq |p-q|=D$. It follows that $L(\gamma)=L(\gamma')+L(\gamma'')\geq 2D$.

Comment: the idea in my attempt was choose $r$ satisfying the condition of Jung's theorem to ensure that the closed ball with center $r$ would contain the curve and so that I would get that $D \leq \frac{L}{2}$, but your proof is very easy. I understood, thanks a lot!